# jenkinsfile fail when I'm using docker in it

Tags: android, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm using **Jenkins 2.263.1** & I want to use **docker** with **pipeline**.
My jenkinsfile is:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
           image 'android-build:android-gradle'
           args '-v $PWD/Android:/app -w /app'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'cd /app && ./gradlew build'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Started by user bani ertebat mahan
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git http://git.banicodevelopers.com/ci-cd/android-app.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential cd5d4a9e-e5e5-4808-b1a4-dcac90da701f
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url http://git.banicodevelopers.com/ci-cd/android-app.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://git.banicodevelopers.com/ci-cd/android-app.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 1.8.3.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress http://git.banicodevelopers.com/ci-cd/android-app.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision d02dcbf66909c49106ea102d94c42df03d424cc4 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f d02dcbf66909c49106ea102d94c42df03d424cc4 # timeout=10
Commit message: "remove --rm options"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 64ad06f998001cb9cbedb8b88df32cfe8a86b679 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . android-build:android-gradle
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 998:996 -v $PWD/Android:/app -w /app -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** android-build:android-gradle cat
$ docker top c8729930a9b86c9ea66bfd674e233c75778d61376edfb7278d930acc6401595a -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./gradlew build
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App@tmp/durable-83d3c6ea/script.sh: 1: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App@tmp/durable-83d3c6ea/script.sh: ./gradlew: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 c8729930a9b86c9ea66bfd674e233c75778d61376edfb7278d930acc6401595a
$ docker rm -f c8729930a9b86c9ea66bfd674e233c75778d61376edfb7278d930acc6401595a
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Despite me never defining **-w,-d,-u,-t options** in my jenkisfile, they are being defined.

I mean just define **one -w option** but, it also define for `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/`

I have added jenkins user to docker group.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you think `+ ./gradlew build /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android-App@tmp/durable-83d3c6ea/script.sh` is the best possible description for your question title ?

Comment: No, What is your suggestion?

Comment: well, your question title is usually in the form of a question, something others can see and understand exactly what you're asking, so you should try to change it into a question by explaining what you're trying to do or what isn't working

Comment: Key error message is: ./gradlew: not found. Your docker image does not have gradlew in its path for the user.

Comment: Do this work is necessary while I determine -w option for it

Comment: why doesn't it consider /app directory as a working directory?

Answer (score 1):

> Despite me never defining -w,-d,-u,-t options in my jenkisfile, they are being defined.

I don't think it's explicitly mentioned in the [Jenkins + Docker docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/), but Pipeline does all of this setup for you — your workspace is automatically mounted into the Docker container. This is why you see Jenkins setting various options when it calls `docker run`.

For most tools, you just need to run the container, without any particular setup required. Or is there a particular reason that your build has to occur in the `/app` directory of the container?

I would try a more minimal Pipeline, as shown in the docs:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'android-build:android-gradle'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh './gradlew build'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir,
Can you please guide me to use the docker image for android build creation on Jenkin. Please check my question on the same [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68363485/3946958)